# Complex-valued change of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I have a function $f : \mathbb{R}^{2}\ni (x,y) \to f(x,y) \in\mathbb{C}$, I can define the change of variables $z = x + iy, \bar{z} = x - iy$, so that $f$ is now a function of $(z,\bar{z})$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} -i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} +i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$.

In what sense is this change of coordinates defined? In particular, what is the domain of the function $f(z,\bar{z})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it is a function of $z$ only because $\overline z$ is a function of $z$.

Now $z$ is in the complex plane which is homeomorphic to  $\mathbb R^2$ with elements of the form $(x,y)$.

To read how to complex plane is constructed read here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere

Comment: So that means that $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}$ and $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\bar{z}}}$ should be understood as notation only?

Comment: @GenoWhirl, let $f(z)= 2z+\overline z$ then $\frac {df}{dz}=2$ and $\frac {df}{d\overline z}= 1$. Just see $z$ as variable and $d\overline z$ as a function of $z$.